# Continuity of a function tg/cos+tg

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I have a problem with this function:

$$\ \begin{cases} \dfrac{a \tan (x) }{\cos(x) + \tan(x)}&x\in (0, \frac{\pi}{2}) \\ e^x-c &x\in\Bbb R\setminus (0, \frac{\pi}{2}) \end{cases} $$

I have to prove it is continuous. After comparing limits for $x=0$, I got
$\ e^0-c=0 \Rightarrow c=1 $

However, I have a problem with $\ x=\frac{\pi}{2} $ since tg doesn't exist for such $x$. How can I solve this problem and calculate $a$?

Comment: The tan finctions isn't defined at $\frac\pi2$, but the expressions of your function both have a limit at $\frac\pi 2$. These limits  have to be the same.

Comment: It means that excepting $\ \frac{\pi}{2} $ it is continuous, for x=0 it is continuous for c=1 and any a, otherwise - continuous regardlessly the value of a, c?

Comment: I am really confused. How can I calculate the limit, if tan isn't defined?

Comment: The lack of definition of a function at $\pi/2$ certainly doesn't mean it doesn't have a limit at $\pi/2. \qquad$

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying the numerator and the denominator of the fraction by $\cos x$ yields:
\begin{align}
& \lim_{x\,\uparrow\,\pi/2} \frac{\tan x}{\cos x+ \tan x} \\[8pt]
= {} & \lim_{x\,\uparrow\,\pi/2} \frac{\sin x}{\cos^2 x + \sin x} = 1.
\end{align}
So you need to choose the suitable value of the coefficient $a$ accordingly.

Comment: Does it mean that $\ a=e^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-1 $ ?

Comment: @Question : Yes. $\qquad$